# Moleculer and micro front-end services

Tags: reactjs, angular, microservices, moleculer

Is there a way to make micro frontends in the molecules framework? So one *api/angular* address would be angular and a drugin, e.g. *api/react* would be react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can. In my [home-portal](https://github.com/home-portal/core) project, I'm using Moleculer on the frontend side with micro-frontends concept, every module is running separately (and written with different frameworks) and communicated each other via Moleculer protocol.

Comment: Wow man, nice work, congratulations and thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/). single-spa is a framework for bringing together multiple JavaScript microfrontends in a frontend application.

Comment: You're right, this framework 'Single-spa' is dedicated to micro frontends, however I would like to use Moleculer because I use it in the project